# How to do some operation after web another page is loaded?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have some JavaScript code to fill some table of page1 and auto click its submit button, then it jump to another page2.

What I want is to execute some other codes after page2 is fully loaded. I know methods like `window.onload` and `jQuery.ready` but i don't know how to set this method to page2. For example if i write window.onload then the window reference to the current page.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are the unique identifiers for each page? Can you use the URL? Can you use a unique container ID?

Comment: yes i know url but the page 2 is not written by me so i can't add something like id or class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it the following way.

**example :**

Add unique identification classes to each of the page body.

**page 1**

```
<body class='page1'></body>
```

**page 2**

```
<body class='page2'></body>
```

**JavaScript**

in your javascript file, use the following to run the code.

```
if($('body').hasClass('page1')){
    //run page 1 code
}else{ // You can add a second if just to check if it's page 2
    //run page 2 code
}
```

Then import the file to both pages at the bottom of the body tag. the script will run as needed.

**Update**

To get the current browser url just use `window.location.href` to get the url. The url is a unique page identifier so just update the condition to the following.

```
if(window.location.href == 'page1-url'){
    //run page 1 code
}else{ // You can add a second if just to check if it's page 2
    //run page 2 code
}
```

I would prefer using the `window.location.pathname` since it would just return the page path without the host, but the above will work too.

Comment: ye but the problem is both page1 and page2 are not written by me thus i cannot add anything like class or id

Comment: is there any unique classes or page names that you can use to identify the pages. You don't need to add anything to the page. just look for a unique static class for each page and use it to identify each page!

Comment: there's no identifier of body and iframe, is url any use here?

Comment: if u can use the url to identify each page, there's no issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$( document ).ready()` if page 2 is a new document.

If "page 2" is at a scroll point in the same document, you can use an if statement with the scroll point using `.scroll()`.  Add your script in the head of your new document or a link to a new js file.

Comment: what if i can't use jquery here... since i am using python program to call my js code and i can't use jquery due to some reason...